# Missing romance dialog option in Greedfall

Tags: greedfall

I'm playing Greedfall (via Steam, no DLC), and have just completed Vasco's first personal quest "A Name For the Family." I have gained experience points and Vasco's relationship with me increased as well.

According to the guides, the next thing I should do to romance him is select the "Ask him if he has any happy memories." dialog option.

I don't see that option available, however:

[image: Dialog options]

> Ask him ...
>
> - Whether he is mad at you
> - Whether he wished he was never given to the Nauts

Both [this guide](https://www.thegamer.com/greedfall-vasco-romance-guide/) and [this other guide](https://www.ign.com/wikis/greedfall/Romance_in_GreedFall) both indicate that I should be asking about the happy memories, and the second guide also confirms that the gender of the main character doesn't matter (unlike with some of the other companions.)

The second guide sounds like I should be asking about the happy memories while in the process of completing the quest (eg. when I return to him after stealing his personnel file), but there are no dialog options available during that sequence -- it's fully scripted.

Is there something else I need to do to have this option appear?